# Adding subject line to email that will constantly change

Tags: email

Can i pull data from text on a page and add it to subject line on an email link?  We are hoping to populate the subject line with a 6 digit alpha numeric PIN # that will be unique for every customer.  The PIN # will display on the page that the mailto link appears on but customers either forget to add the PIN # to their email or type it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  You can add a lot in `mailto` links.  To add a subject, construct your link like this:

```
<a href='mailto:someone@somewhere.com?subject:Your subject text here'>Send Email</a>
```

More tips and tricks [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/mailto-links/).

Answer (score 0):

Dylan's answer is pointing to the right direction, but probably you will need to write some javascript to achieve the goal.

For example, if your email link is

```
<a id="emailUs" href="mailto:abc@xyz.com">Email Us</a>
```

You can use the following JS code to dynamically set the `mailto` value

```
var customerPIN = sample_PIN_12345;/*I believe you will have a way to get the PIN # from the page*/    
var emailLink = document.getElementById("emailUs");    
emailLink.href="mailto:abc@xyz.com?subject:any text followed by the PIN " 
+ customerPIN + " any text after the PIN";
```

You can use [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) if the email link does not have an id.

You can also use jQuery to achieve the above, but I didn't make the assumption that you are using it.